# How to add gitlab autentification to kiwitcms?

Tags: kiwi-tcms

In kiwitcms demo https://bfg.kiwitcms.ami.com/ I see option for gitlab autentification.

How to add this plugin to kiwitcms?

[image: kiwitcms demo]